# How to Find the Limit Correctly?

Tags: limits

I am refreshing my Calculus memory, and bump into this example (need feedback):

$$f(x)= 
  \begin{cases}
   -x,    & \text{if } x < 0 \\
   x,        & \text{if } 0 \le x < 1 \\
   1 + x,    & \text{if } x \ge 1
  \end{cases}$$

I have to find the limits / state if it does not exist. Correct me if I am wrong:

- $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)$ does not exist
- $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} f(x)$  does not exist
- $f(1) = 2$
- $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^{+}} f(x) = 2$

Are my answers correct?

This is the plot
[image: plot]

Comment: First one is wrong, the others are correct. Can you explain your reasoning behind the first conclusion?

Comment: I plot the image and the graph of $-x$ has a gap to $x=0$ and I thought by using limit from left and right, it does not exist.

Comment: The plot must be incorrect. Posting the plot would improve the question.

Comment: I post the plot above

Comment: The plot should not have a gap. What is $f(-0.1)$?

Comment: I am using Julia to plot it and use ylims and xlims for each plot of the function. f(-0.1) = 0.1

Comment: @FreyatheGoddess The graph doesn't correspond to the definition for $f(x)$.

Comment: I think the -x graph is wrong since it should have no gap. I wrongly thought it has no limit before.

Comment: @FreyatheGoddess in your code for plotting, you likely are not plotting the first part of f(x) for x=0. I know technically the first part does not mathematically belong to x=0, but as all plots are just small amount of straight lines on screen, when you plot piecewise functions, make sure you include values of `x` for corner cases in both sides of `x`.

Comment: Hi all. Guys and Girls here.. this is my thought on the gap. $f(x) = -x$ and on the condition for it is $x < 0$ that is why it should have a gap / hole. Based on substituting to the function we get the same value for the left-hand and right-hand limit. But, I am still confused on  $f(x) = -x$ , if $x <0$ that does not include 0 so it should be a hollow point there for $-x$ graph.

Answer (score 6):

The limit of $f$ for $x \to 0$ exists and is $0$. Your other answers are correct.

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted. It may not contain everything that the other answer does, but it is not wrong.

Comment: Yeah — was confused as well — its pointing out the same mistake by op

Comment: I am not downvoted it, too many pessimistic I guess on this forum. Not everyone has learned like those who downvoted. No one is smarter, only learn sooner. That's all

Comment: @robjohn I didn't downvote, but you have enough points that you know "not factually correct" isn't the only reason people do so. This answer in particular could be improved by showing why 0 is correct and attempting to address the mistake that led to the incorrect answer.

Comment: @TheRubberDuck: your comment, "This answer in particular could be improved by showing why 0 is correct and attempting to address the mistake that led to the incorrect answer", at least, is better feedback than a downvote. The question asked which statements were correct, and since there was no explanation of the first statement, it is hard to know what the error was. Later answers do provide justification that the limit exists, but the problem seems to have been in the plotting software. As I suggested, the added plot improves the question quite a bit.

Comment: Actually, the question, before the plot, could have been considered a collection of 4 PSQs, and probably shouldn't have been answered until after it had been improved.

Comment: Mathematics becomes the most beautiful science is because of the process of proving the theorems and so on. StackExchange creates the downvote to take data to be processed to become knowledge. I personally think that downvoting just because we "think" we are smarter is not a wise thing to do, some are lucky have facility and able to learn comfortably, while some can't / have to be farmers, feeding their families. No equal start for everyone. Some can be rich in USA because they have connection and have time to establish the business + living in USA instead of living in poor country.

Answer (score 5):

As others have pointed out, the limit at $0$ exists. $f$ is equal to $|x|$ for $x < 1$. Since $|x|$ is continuous at $0$ so is this function.

Formally, $\forall \epsilon \in (0,1), |x|< \epsilon \implies |f|<\epsilon \implies \lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0$

Answer (score 5):

This is (presumably) what you've plotted:

$$
y = 
\begin{cases}
 -x,    & \text{if } x < -1 \\
 x,        & \text{if } 0 \le x < 1 \\
 1 + x,    & \text{if } x \ge 1
\end{cases}
$$

And this is what the graph should have looked like.

[image: What the plot should look like]

Relying on tools is nice, but it's important to make sure that they are doing what you want them to do. For example, if I did this graph by hand, I might add a little hollow circle at $\{1,1\}$ to indicate that when $x$ is $1$, $y$ isn't $1$, it's $2$.  As the other answers noted, it's entirely possible to solve this problem without a plot.

Comment: Thanks for the plot.. I understand it is important to put hollow circle for those that has no limit at that point.

Comment: Wait a minute, based on the case, the f(x) = -x is for x < 0, that means there is a hollow point at x=0 for the -x graph.

Comment: @FreyatheGoddess visually, there would also be a solid point at $x=0$ for the $x$ graph, and overlaying the two gives a solid point

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, we have that

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} x =0$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-} -x =0$$

therefore, since both one side limit are equal, we can conclude that

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)=0$$

Comment: thanks for this. Because using both equations of $x$ and $-x$ produce the same result which is 0, the limit is 0.

Comment: @FreyatheGoddess Yes exactly!